How to code in react-native app as it contains typescript files
I have started learning react-native and created a app with expo go it is running fine but I don't know how to process further and to write simple programs in those files and all the files are typescript files they are downloaded inbuilt while I have created the create-native app. I need to start a new react-native can anyone tell the process for that visited youtube but I am getting errors for those commands.
I have started learning react-native and created a app with expo go it is running fine but I don't know how to process further and to write simple programs in those files and all the files are typescript files they are downloaded inbuilt while I have created the create-native app. I need to start a new react-native can anyone tell the process for that visited youtube but I am getting errors for those commands

By default react native projects now will be created in typescript but it still supports js modules
https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#:~:text=Using%20JavaScript%20Instead%20of%20TypeScript,and%20will%20not%20be%20typechecked.
You can manually convert the files.
Only 3-4 files will be needing conversion from typescript to js and then you will have no issue in doing so
let me know if you need any help converting those files
